# Phrases similar to "one man's trash is another man's treasure"

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for a similar phrase to: "one man's trash is another man's treasure."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar in meaning or in structure?

Comment: What's wrong with that phrase? Why are you looking for a different one?

Answer (score 6):

See the answers to [Origin of “one man's trash is another man's treasure”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60429/origin-of-one-mans-trash-is-another-mans-treasure):

One man's meat is another man's poison

One man's ceiling is another man's floor

One's man's pleasure is another's pain

A thing which is a sin to one is a blessing to another

One man's loss is another man's profit

One man's fault is another man's lesson

Et al

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an idiomatic phrase which refers to the differences in likings that people may have you can say:

[One man's meat is another man's poison](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+man%27s+meat+is+another+man%27s+poison):

> - You may not like something that I like. The phrase, which was first written by the Roman poet Lucretius, was appropriated to refer to any situation where two people disagree over something.
> - Prov. Something that one person likes may be distasteful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

When I used to work as a florist, by the end of a busy holiday there would be only mismatched dregs to make arrangements out of. So, we had a little game: Someone would make the ugliest flower arrangement possible, and we'd put a giant mismatched bow in the middle of it, and we'd watch to see who bought it. Invariably, a customer would pick it up, deem it "exquisite", and buy it. And, invariably, an older woman we worked with would say,**"There's a seat for every ass."**

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for another idiom that means "One person might dislike this, but another person might like it," you could go with ["Beauty is in the eye of the beholder."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beauty+is+in+the+eye+of+the+beholder) The Free Dictionary defines it as "Different people have different ideas about what is beautiful."

Answer (score -2):

"[Where there's muck there's brass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/where-there's-muck-there's-brass)".